# azure website deployment slot refuses new connection string

Tags: azure

If I add a new connection string to the 'root' website using the portal it saves ok.

If I add a new connection string to the staging deployment slot website I get an error: "Updating the configuration for web app 'foo' failed"

Plus "Please try again. If the problem persists, contact support"

...but my subscription only allows Billing support so that's no use.

Does Azure not allow configuration changed in non root deployment? I though the config settings were not swapped so I'm a bit baffled by this behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can get the new Connection Strings to Save if I use the new portal. I can live with that.